# Checking for Web Service connectivity

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8.1

I've developed a simple Web Service and a Windows Phone 8 app to consume it.
Everything works as intended but the way my current (working) code stands, it's assuming the Web Service to always be running and available. Seeing as that may not always be the case, I'd like to try and add some kind of connectivity testing before I start sending requests. I've read that there's no straightforward way of being certain that the WS is up and running other than querying it somehow.

With that in mind, here's what my **LoadData** method structure looks like (**Feb. 26th**):

```
public void LoadData(string articleCode = null)
{
    try
    {
        this.ArticleItems.Clear();
        MyServiceSoapClient ws = new MyServiceSoapClient();
        CheckWebService(); 
        if (this.isWebServiceUp)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(articleCode))
            {
                ws.GetBasicDataAsync(articleCode);
                ws.GetBasicDataCompleted += Ws_GetBasicDataCompleted;
                //(irrelevant code supressed for clarity)

                this.IsDataLoaded = true;                   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ArticleItems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = "Could not connect to Web Service." });
            ws.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

And it still throws an [unhandled CommunicationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz1IZ.png) error.

**EDIT**: After taking into consideration both suggestions and doing some searching, I've tried to set up a "heartbeat"-type method but it's not working correctly. Asynchronous programming is a relatively new paradigm for me so I most likely am missing something but here goes my attempt at an implementation thus far (getting a **"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'"** exception):

```
public void CheckWebService()
{ 
    try
    {
        Uri wsURL = new Uri("http://localhost:60621/WebService1.asmx");
        //try accessing the web service directly via its URL
        var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(wsURL);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        //next line throws: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.Browser.OHWRAsyncResult' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'."
        using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ServiceCallback), request))
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error locating web service");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.FaultException fe)
    {
        this.ArticleItems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = fe.Message });
    }
    catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ce)
    {
        this.ArticleItems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = ce.Message });
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException we)
    {
        this.ArticleItems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = we.Message });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.ArticleItems.Add(new ItemViewModel() { LineOne = ex.Message });
    }
}

private void ServiceCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        using (var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
        {
            if (response != null && response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                this.isWebServiceUp = true;
                request.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a "heartbeat" method to your service. That is a method that simply sends back an acknowledge message. At the beginning of your session call the heartbeat, if you get back the ack, you're golden, if not, the service is, for some reason, not available.

Comment: I've tried doing so but rather unsucessfully. Updated the post to reflect changes.